# ubuntu touch S6102 no bootloader

Tags: android, bootloader, samsung

I have a Samsung S6102 with android 2.3.6. I have tried to install ubuntu touch while following the instalation instuctions on your page step by step. However I have a problem. While android is normally working ubuntu - adb can recognize the device but in the bootloader not.
The command "$ adb devices" (in the android) shows the device but the command "$ fastboot devices" in the android bootloader do not.
I tried to find anything on the internet how to continue but i do not have a clue how.
What do I need to do?